# Apache Camel: How to use custom AggregationStrategy

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like use my custom `AggregationStrategy` which extends `UseOriginalAggregationStrategy`: `OriginalPropertyAggregationStrategy`

This new custom `AggregationStrategy` has a constructor to accept a instance of `Exchange`

```
public OriginalPropertyAggregationStrategy(Exchange original, String... properties) {
    super(original, true);
    this.properties = properties;
}
```

I intend to pass an instance of this Strategy in Java DSL but do not know how to pass an Exchange:

```
.split().method(SplitHelper.class, "invokeSplitter").aggregationStrategy(new OriginalPropertyAggregationStrategy(???, "MSG_RECOVERY_BEAN"))
.stopOnException()
.streaming().parallelProcessing().executorService(threadPoolExecutor)
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't choose what to pass to your strategy. **You have to implement the [Interface `AggregationStrategy`](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/AggregationStrategy.html)**.

Since the interface is given, you don't have to worry about how to pass the arguments, Camel does it for you. You just have to reference the class that implements the strategy.

```
.aggregationStrategy(new FancyAggregationStrategy())
```